# Warning: Input string not available in this locale

Tags: r, r-markdown

Rstudio Version 1.0.136

R Version 3.3.2

It's strange that when I run code(it has Chinese comment in code)line by line in a  `.Rmd` file with Rmarkdown，console will print a warning as follow:

```
Warning message:
In strsplit(code, "\n", fixed = TRUE) :
   input string 1 is invalid in this locale
```

It's so annoying ,because every line it will appear.
I has change default text encoding in RStudio's setting ,but neither UTF-8 nor BG2312 can prevent this warning messag appearing.
Please notice that it just appear when a run code line by line ,if I select a chunk an press button to produce a html，warning doesn't appear.
my code is as follows:

````
```{r}
da=read.table("m-intcsp7309.txt",header=T)
head(da)
# date intel sp三列
length(da$date)
# 444数据
intc=log(da$intc+1)
# 测试
plot(cars)
# 测试警告信息
plot(cars)
# 为什么会出现警告？
plot(cars)
```
````

I have test it's not arise from Chinese comment,I meet it when I only use English
just now.
Here is more information:

```
Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936;
     LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936;
     LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936;
     LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936"
```

Comment: Add the output from `Sys.getlocale()`

Comment: @Martin   I have done it.

Comment: Try  `Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','C')`

Comment: @Martin It seems ok,thank you for your answer sincerely,but why?I have search on Internet,nobody other has this problem.

Comment: It seems like the text file you are reading in contains a character that is not available in your original chinese locale. Not sure how it was encoded etc. The warning is carried on for every executed line even though it did not occur again.

Comment: @Martin Sadly,everytime I restart Rstudio,it may occur again，and locale setting has restored,I need to setlocale again.

Answer (score 26):

I had a similar issue with `gsub()` and was able to resolve it, without changing the locale, simply by setting `useBytes = TRUE`. The same should work in `strsplit()`. From the documentation:

> If TRUE the matching is done byte-by-byte rather than character-by-character, and inputs with marked encodings are not converted.

Comment: I think the `useBytes = TRUE` option is the best way to solve the issue

Answer (score 15):

Embed this directly in the Rmarkdown script that contains the Chinese character comment(s):

```
Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','C')
```

If you just run it in the R console before running the rmarkdown script, that may temporarily change the setting and work, but as you said, it won't stay that way if you restart R. That's why it's better to directly embed that line into the script(s) that need it.

Comment: @lemmingxuan - Does this answer your question?

Comment: More specifically, `Sys.setlocale('LC_CTYPE','C')` worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: It worked for me as well, but I don't really know what this command does

Answer (score 1):

Setting `useBytes = TRUE` in gsub seems to work best. For example, `gsub('pattern text','replacement text', useBytes = TRUE)`

Comment: how is this not a duplicate answer of the one by crsh?

Answer (score 0):

If you get this warning just after or during building your vignettes during the `check()` of your package, then it is probably linked to this problem: https://github.com/r-lib/rcmdcheck/issues/140
If you update {processx} and {rcmdcheck}, this should work better.